# Oracle SQL Query set default value if category is not present

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need help in creating a SQL query.

Below are the tables I'm using for my SQL query.

- `Task` table (specifies different task)
- `Task Type` table (name & type of the task)
- `Work` table (get the tasks associated with different work ids) and Work Type (defines work type and work category) table

The categories under work type table are "D", "I", "A"

Here is my query below

```
SELECT SUM(t.cost)               AS Cost,
  wt.jobCategory                 AS Cat,
  TO_CHAR(t.taskStart, 'MON-YY') AS taskDate
FROM task t,
  WORK w,
  work_type wt
WHERE w.workId   = t.jobId
AND w.workType  IN(a,b,c,d)
AND t.taskType  IN(1,2,4,5,6,7,8)
AND wt.workType  = w.workType
AND t.taskStart >= to_date('01/04/2013 01:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND t.taskStop   < to_date('03/04/2014 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.taskStart, 'YYYYMM'),
  TO_CHAR(t.taskStart, 'MON-YY'),
  wt.workCategory
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(t.taskStart, 'YYYYMM') ASC;
```

Output of the query is

```
##Cost        Cat       TaskDate##
-----------------------------------------
26243.13       D         MAY-13     
6716.7         A         MAY-13     
14839.55       D         JUN-13  
4653.61        I         JUN-13
59209.46       D         JUL-13
10018.12       I         JUL-13
22976.54       D         AUG-13
7363.35        I         AUG-13
9256.15        D         SEP-13
4054.83        A         SEP-13
371.1          D         OCT-13
44.64          I         OCT-13
480            A         NOV-13
73618.24       D         NOV-13
14293.47       I         NOV-13
```

Can you please help me on the above query where I'm expecting the category value (cat) to 0 if no value for that specified month

Expected output would be like

---

```
##Cost        Cat       TaskDate##

26243.13       D         MAY-13     
6716.7         A         MAY-13     
0              I         MAY-13     
14839.55       D         JUN-13  
4653.61        I         JUN-13
0              A         JUN-13     
59209.46       D         JUL-13
10018.12       I         JUL-13
0              A         JUL-13     
22976.54       D         AUG-13
7363.35        I         AUG-13
0              A         AUG-13     
9256.15        D         SEP-13
4054.83        A         SEP-13
0              I         SEP-13     
371.1          D         OCT-13
44.64          I         OCT-13
0              A         OCT-13     
480            A         NOV-13
73618.24       D         NOV-13
14293.47       I         NOV-13
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: And marc_s's comment is not just advice about coding style, but the 'new' style joins can actually solve your problem, so be sure to read that article.